# MySQL не ищет по точному вхождению

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте, 
Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail_black_list` (
  `id` int(55) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `1c_done` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `email_2` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=751 ;
```

Запросы:

```
SELECT * FROM `mail_black_list` WHERE email='puh-169961@ukr.net'  
SELECT * FROM `mail_black_list` WHERE email LIKE '%puh-169961@ukr.net%'
```

Не выдают ничего, но запись с `email "puh-169961@ukr.net"` точно есть. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что таблицы `ambar_mail_black_list` не существует?

Comment: уже исправил)

Comment: Тогда из чего следует, что такая запись есть?

Comment: я их сам добавлял, и phpmyadmin показывает что запись есть

Comment: SELECT * FROM `mail_black_list` WHERE email LIKE '%169961%'  
Если такая выборка найдет e-mail, то проверьте, не русская ли, случаем е в .net